# if >= condition changing the value of my elements in a global array

Tags: c++, c

Hi all Thanks in advance for your time,

I have the following global arrays defined

```
int n_inactive=0;
long cc_no_issue[4]={0};
int issue[4];
```

and I increment the values

```
for(size_t k=0;k<contexts.size();k++)
{
    if(issue[k]==0)
        {

            cc_no_issue[k]++;

        }
    else {
            if(cc_no_issue[k]>=20)
            {
                n_inactive--;

            }
        cc_no_issue[k]=0; 

        }


    if(cc_no_issue[k]==20)
        n_inactive++;

}
```

Then I use a conditional if >=

```
if(cc_no_issue[disp_context_id]>=20)
```

after that my values are incremented over and over and then the condition is never satisfied and my program aborts.

When I use a conditional if ==

```
  if(cc_no_issue[disp_context_id]==20)
```

The values stay and are not changed.

please note to avoid confusion disp_context_id is a number 0-3

Can anyone please provide some analysis as to why a if statement with a >= condition will change the value of my elements within the array

Thanks so much again.

Edit Here is how I am using the if statement

```
          if(cc_no_issue[disp_context_id]>=10)
        {


            contexts_left.erase(contexts_left.begin()+current_context);
            continue;
        }
```

Edit: Here are some values for when i use ==
 7 10  3  9
10 13  6 12
 2 10 56  8
 4  0 58 10
 0  1 10  7
 3  0 13 10
10  2  1 17
 0  8  7 10
 2 10  9 12
 3 11 10 13
 3 29 28 10
 0 134 10 115
 0  2 10 18
 1 10 18 26

And now when i change it to >=
 2 6904 6904 6878
 2 6904 6904 6878
 0 6905 6905 6879
 0 6905 6905 6879
 0 6905 6905 6879
 0 6906 6906 6880
 0 6906 6906 6880
 0 6906 6906 6880
 0 6907 6907 6881
 0 6907 6907 6881
 0 6907 6907 6881
 0 6908 6908 6882
 0 6908 6908 6882
 0 6908 6908 6882
 0 6909 6909 6883
 0 6909 6909 6883
 0 6909 6909 6883
 0 6910 6910 6884
 0 6910 6910 6884
 0 6910 6910 6884
 0 6911 6911 6885
 0 6911 6911 6885
 0 6911 6911 6885
 0 6912 6912 6886

The difference is easily notable

@Rob, Rob thanks for sticking with me. I really cant write a comparable compilable program because of many headerfiles and a datastructure. I can try to tell you in words

This cc_no_issue[4]={0}; array is defined initially as 0
I also have a array allocated for an issue array issue[4]

In another function of the code I have it to increment the elements 0-3 of Issue array

Then in the current function I have a check for elements 0-3 if any of them are equal to 0 then increment the cc_no_issue array.

I then reset the current element to 0 every time cc_no_issue[k]>=20

several lines down I want to remove a element from a data structure if a condition is met.
That condition is within a while loop

```
           if(cc_no_issue[k]>=10) 
              {
                use .erase to remove it from the array
                continue; 
              }
```

I hope it helps to clear things up.

Comment: Pleas post a short example (real code) that demonstrates the problem. Your above snippit is missing half the variables you are talking about.

Comment: A >= comp will not change your values - at least not per the code snippet you provide. You need to add how the final conditional ties into the code you already submitted to understand. (also: check for simple errors, such as typing '=' when you meant '==' because that could change values).

Comment: I should have shown the actual if statement i suppose. Here it is
      if(cc_no_issue[disp_context_id]>=10)
  {

  contexts_left.erase(contexts_left.begin()+current_context);
  continue;
        }

This increments the values over and over again. I see that I have the contiune...but its a

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, compilable program that demonstrates the problem you are having. In reducing your program to a minimal form, you may discover for yourself what the problem is. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: The point of reducing to a minimal program is to get rid of all of the header files and data structures that are not related to the problem at hand. Just keep slashing out major sections of your program (always on a *copy* of your source, so you don't lose anything) and rechecking to see if the problem still occurs. Eventually, you will either have a short program, or you will have found the line of code that breaks your program.

Comment: How do you "use .erase to remove it from the array"?

Comment: @m3rc: Are you erasing items from the array you are looping over? That's generally a bad idea because it's easy to skip over items in the array if the iterator (`k` or `disp_context_id`, not sure what's the real) is not adjusted properly.

Answer (score 0):

If `context.size() > 4`, you will write outside the bounds of `cc_no_issue`. That would certainly be one reason for your program aborting.

You might also be outside the bounds of `issue` as well. If you dereferenced an unavailable address, that would also abort your program.